# Replacing a variable value doesn't work as expected in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create the following line into SQL statement:

If `account code` is **XING** replace the `strategy` to **GRE**?

I have the following which is not working:

```
/if($_Account Master.Account Code CNS$,/replace($_Account Master.Strategy$,$_Account Master.Strategy$,GRE))
```

Please let me know the correct method.

Comment: Doesn't look like TSQL

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

I update the title. How about now?

Comment: Look at teh case statement

Comment: Please post a more complete part of your code. Is it in a `SELECT`, an `UPDATE` statement, a T-SQL `IF` ?

Comment: `/if(` and `/replace` is not valid TSQL code, please clarify with syntactically correct code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about replacing value in a variable based on variable go with

```
IF @AcciountCode = 'XING' @Strategy = 'GRE'
```

But I have a feeling you need to update respective fields in the table. If so, you need something like

```
UPDATE [Account Master] SET Strategy = 'GRE' WHERE [Account Code] = 'XING'
```

Comment: I will give your code a go as well :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it in a select statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [Account Code] = 'XING' THEN 'GRE' ELSE [Strategy] END AS [Strategy]
FROM [Account Master]
```